# Angular2 pre-bootstrap loading screen (splash screen) with Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-2

How can I implement an splash screen that for example, slowly fades after bootstrapping is complete.

I'm reading [this](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3105-creating-a-pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-in-angular-2-rc-1.htm) tutorial (the second approach), but it's written for systemjs.

and to save time, I already know this one:

```
.loading {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .8s ease-in-out;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
        color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    z-index: -1;
}

my-app:empty + .loading {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 100;
}

my-app:empty + .loading h1 {
    color: #EEE;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

that's not clean!

Comment: I've followed this guide: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3105-creating-a-pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-in-angular-2-rc-1.htm

Comment: @FabrizioCaldarelli, It's the same. no webpack :|

Comment: I'm also using webpack, but that guide not add configuration to webpack (it is all inside the index.html).

Comment: @FabrizioCaldarelli, There is, actually. the `global.bootstrapping = System.import("app" ).then(...);` part from **system.config.js**. I'm talking about the **second** approach.

Comment: What strikes you as not clean about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do this quite easily. I followed the example of [bennadel's blog](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3105-creating-a-pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-in-angular-2-rc-1.htm) but slightly modified it so that the html is something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        // CSS style with `transition` animation
        // so that when you apply a class i.e. `.loaded { opacity: 0 }`
        // it will smoothly fade out
        // Also this needs to be with a z-index: 9999 so that it will
        // show over `app-root`.
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <app-root></app-root>

    <div id="my-splash-screen">
        Loading animation or what ever...
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And then in the `src` folder of the Angular 2+ app you will find the `main.ts` file. Initially the content of the file will be the default such as:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The key here is to append a `.then()` before the `.catch()` block in the `platformBrowserDynamic()` part, which does the magic with applying the css class to the `my-splash-screen`, waits for a short moment and then removes the splash. In other words, the code will become something like this:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
.then(() => {
    let splashScreen = document.getElementById('my-splash-screen');
    splashScreen.setAttribute('class', 'loaded');
    setTimeout(function(){ splashScreen.remove(); }, 1300); // change the timeout to be almost the same as the transition animation.
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```